# PowerShell get-childitem refusal to exclude directory

Tags: powershell

I am trying to simply search for files in a network share, but exclude a useless directory. I know there is the `-exclude` option for `get-childitem`.

However, when I try to run the command  `get-childitem -recurse -exclude \\share\folder\excludeddir`, PowerShell ignores the -exclude parameter. Any and all permutations of the exclusion path have been attempted.

Why is powershell ignoring the -exclude parameter? Is there any way to simply exclude a directory without having to write multiple lines of code? And no, the method of piping to `| ? { $_.FullName -inotmatch 'excludeddir' }` is not usable, as it is completely ignored by powershell if it is used within a network share.

Comment: `-Exclude` applies to the leaf of the target item. So `-Exclude 'Desktop'` would exclude `c:\users\user\desktop` directory but not the files underneath. It is not smart enough to know *"i excluded a directory so stop searching underneath"*.

Comment: Can you explain why piping to where is not usable? I don't know what *it breaks the recursive search and text searching functionality* means.

Comment: I just don't see why `get-childitem -recurse |? {($_.Fullname -notmatch '\\Desktop\\') -and !($_.PSISContainer -and $_.Name -match 'Desktop$')}` doesn't do what you are intending. If you only care about the Desktop folder in a user's profile, then `get-childitem -recurse -exclude | ? { $_.FullName -notmatch 'c:\\users\\[^\\]+\\Desktop' }` works.

Comment: @AdminOfThings , It does do what I'm intending, but due to MicroShafts infinite wisdom and skillful design, it breaks `select-string` later on in other pipes. As I clearly stated, piping to `? { $_.FullName -notmatch` is not a viable solution for my issue.

Comment: It would be best to just post your ultimate goal instead of trying to create an XY problem. Unless your post is merely to just complain about `-Exclude`, which isn’t going to be fixed by anyone here, then nothing you have provided is actually helpful towards a solution.

Comment: I seem to have no issues with recursively searching and piping to `Select-String`. In a case where I want to ignore the file items directly inside of the `Desktop` folder but want to search subfolders of `Desktop` and all other subfolders of my path for `.txt` files, this works for me `get-childitem -recurse -filter '*.txt' -file |? {$_.Directory.Name -notmatch '^Desktop$'} | select-string -pattern 'mystring'`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following if you want to exclude all files within a folder called `Desktop`.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Where {
    $_.Directory.Name -ne 'Desktop'
    } | Select-String -Pattern 'mystring'
```

**Explanation:**

The problem with `-Exclude` is that it only applies to the leaf item of the current item's path. The online documentation falls short in explaining how `-Exclude` works and the idiosyncrasies of it. So if you exclude `Desktop`, any file named `Desktop` or any folder path that ends with a folder named `Desktop` would be excluded. It however, does not exclude any subfolders or subfiles of an excluded directory when `-Recurse` is used. I do not know if that is by design or an oversight.

If you are only searching for files, the `-File` parameter only returns files. Since `FileInfo` objects have a `Directory` property, which is a `DirectoryInfo` object, you can reference its `Name` property to determine the parent directory name of a returned file.

Comment: I modified the question as while this works on normal folders, this is not working in network shares with UNC paths, it simply ignores the exclusion statement and includes files within that directory.